# 2 selector functions seem to cancel each other out

Tags: javascript

I have two selectors setup in a currently, small script.  Whichever one is at top works, whichever one is below the top one, doesn't work or throw an error.  I ran the entire script through the linter with no issues.

Here are the two selectors with the basic function of preventDefault.

```
 var btn = document.getElementById('scandrive');
btn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  myFunction();
});

var getLink = document.querySelector('mylink');
getLink.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alertMe(getLink.href);
});
```

Whichever one is first, works and executes fine.  Also each one relates to a different page, so there shouldn't be any conflicts.

I honestly have been searching to see if maybe I'm not laying out the code right, but nothing has stood out. I'm assuming that typically I can set up a selector at the start, middle, or end.  Also, it may not matter mentioning it but the script link is right above the closing body tag, just in case.  I've tried it in the head but that made no difference.

Edit: Adding the html -

```
<ul class="list-group">
      <a id="mylink" href="link1">Link 1</a>
 </ul>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="scandrive" input type="Submit">Check to scan or update</button>
```

Comment: Please share the HTML.

Comment: what elements are getting selected? are they different elements?

Comment: I just added the relevant html.  The elements are different and separate elements, one is a button, the other an a tag.

Comment: The order your event handlers are defined shouldn't matter.  Does changing to `document.querySelector('#mylink');` fix the problem?

Comment: @RickHitchcock that's what I thought, even though I'm new to it.  No I had the pound sign earlier, makes no difference.  If first it works with either.

Comment: It shouldn't work at all without the pound sign(?)  Can you create a Snippet or JSFiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: The one that is using `getElementById` does NOT work with the pound sign.  The one with querySelector will work with both.  I just did the mdn basics and do not remember seeing anything mentioned about that requirement.  As for a Fiddle, I'm not sure what there is to demonstrate?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this out:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('scandrive');
btn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  myFunction();
});

var getLink = document.getElementById('mylink');
getLink.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alertMe(getLink.getAttribute(href));
});
```

If you want to tag the ID with querySelector, you should pass it just as a css selector (#myLink) and the the HTMLElements do not have the href property so you must extract it through the getAttribute method

Comment: I tried it now on your recommendation (and earlier) but nothing changed.  Also I found the `getAtttribute` was not needed.  When I have the function working I found just the `href` was all it took.